# how to check if a stored procedure that returns value into a table if its been successful or not

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have  a stored procedure that runs a insert statement and it returns a value into a datatable. I must use a datatable thank you in advance :)

my SQL stored procedure

```
begin
Declare @postID int = 0
insert into reviews (customerID, title, review)
values (@cusomerID, @title, @review) 
set @postID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
end
```

the return value is stored in a datatable i would like to check if the insert was successful.

i'm using ajax jquery to do insert which calls the stored procedure and returns a value

method called

```
if (data.Rows[0]["post_ID "] != 0)
            {
                return "successful";
            }
else{
return "failed";
}
```

in javascript

```
if(result != "failed"){
run code
}
```

however it is returning successful even when the insert failed.

any help would be great thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns the last auto-id. In your case it's returning the one before your failed insert.

Try something like

```
BEGIN
    DECARE @postID int = 0
    INSERT INTO reviews (customerID, title, review) VALUES (@cusomerID, @title, @review) 
    IF @@ERROR <> 0
         SET @postID = -1
    ELSE
        SET @postID = (select SCOPE_IDENTITY())
   SELECT @postID
END
```

and in your code, if ID == -1 you know it failed.

Alternatively, you could

```
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    DECARE @postID int = 0
    INSERT INTO reviews (customerID, title, review) VALUES (@cusomerID, @title, @review) 
    SET @postID = (select SCOPE_IDENTITY())        
    SELECT @postID
END
```

and an exception will occur in your code upon any error (transaction is rolled back too).